# .net memory usage reporting difference between task manager and windbg/sos

Tags: memory-management, .net-3.5, windbg, sos

I have a .net application. In task manager it showing 249 MB usage in Memory (private working set) column. Then I attach windb and ran !address –summary command. Below is its result. The memory usage its showing in .NET heap(RegionUsageIsVAD)  is 568 MB. 
Should these two values be same?  Can anyone explain why is so much difference between the two values?

-------------------- Usage SUMMARY --------------------------
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots) Pct(Busy)   Usage
   **22b7c000 (  568816) : 27.12%    64.42%    : RegionUsageIsVAD**
   4a1b3000 ( 1214156) : 57.90%    00.00%    : RegionUsageFree
    e8e6000 (  238488) : 11.37%    27.01%    : RegionUsageImage
    1c00000 (   28672) : 01.37%    03.25%    : RegionUsageStack
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageTeb
    2dda000 (   46952) : 02.24%    05.32%    : RegionUsageHeap
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePageHeap
       1000 (       4) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePeb
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageProcessParametrs
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageEnvironmentBlock
       Tot: 7fff0000 (2097088 KB) Busy: 35e3d000 (882932 KB)

-------------------- Type SUMMARY --------------------------
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots)  Usage
   4a1b3000 ( 1214156) : 57.90%   : 
   11ce9000 (  291748) : 13.91%   : MEM_IMAGE
    9fe9000 (  163748) : 07.81%   : MEM_MAPPED
   1a16b000 (  427436) : 20.38%   : MEM_PRIVATE

-------------------- State SUMMARY --------------------------
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots)  Usage
   2e2a0000 (  756352) : 36.07%   : MEM_COMMIT
   4a1b3000 ( 1214156) : 57.90%   : MEM_FREE
    7b9d000 (  126580) : 06.04%   : MEM_RESERVE

Largest free region: Base 32ce9000 - Size 15377000 (347612 KB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!address is just showing you address space usage.  Some of the memory is paged out.  The working set (memory actually paged in and in use) is much smaller.

Comment: By the way, RegionUsageIsVAD does not just show memory used by the GC heaps.  It shows you everything allocated by VirtualAlloc, file mappings and, I think, some other things as well.